# <T> Stream<T> - don't understand this return-Type

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, return-value

I'm new to Streams and as I was looking at some methods, I saw this return-Type:

```
<T> Stream<T>
```

I don't understand the difference between "`<T> Stream<T>`" and "`Stream<T>`". What does the extra `<T>` do?
Thanks for any help. I tried to google it.

Comment: Show us your code please. It should be stream of some objects with format type parameter `T`

Answer (score 1):

When we deal with generic in java we should know that we can define a generic class or interface like `public interface Stream<T>` so any instant method will use the T type `Stream<T> filter(` but if you define a static method in the same class/interface you should define the generic return type `public static<T> Stream<T> empty()` or if you want to define an instance method with a new generic return type `<R> Stream<R> map(` since you can have a generic method in non generic class.
I hope it helps.
cheers

Answer (score 1):

It's not just specific to `Stream`.

Static generic methods need their own generic declaration (`public static <T>`) separate from the class's generic declaration.

Stream's `concat` method is `static`, as an example,

```
public static <T> Stream<T> concat(Stream<? extends T> a, Stream<? extends T> b)
```

whilst its `filter` method is not.

```
Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate);
```